# How to find the equation of the tangent line to $y=x^2+2x-4$ at $x=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> I'm given a curve $$y=x^2+2x-4$$
>
> How do I find the tangent line to this curve at $x = 2$?

Comment: You should essentially differentiate the quadratic $x^2 + 2x -4$ w.r.t. $x$ and plug in $x=2$. But since you have tagged this "precalculus", do you know how to differentiate a (polynomial) function?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it would be nice to have an answer that showed the differentiating approach

Comment: Actually, that is not a curve. Perhaps, you meant $y=x^2+2x-4,$ which is a real curve in the plane.

Comment: The tangent to the curve $y-(x^2+2x-4)=0$ at $(2,4)$ can be found by translating this point to the origin: $x-2=X, y-4=Y$; $Y+4-((X+2)^2+2(X+2)-4)=0$ or $-X^2+Y-6X=0$. Now the linear terms (or the tangent cone) give the tangent; just translate it back: $Y=6X\to y-4=6(x-2)$ or $y=6x-8$.

Answer (score 18):

Here's an algebraic approach that avoids the explicit use of derivatives.

We are given a quadratic function $f(x) = x^2 + 2x -4$, and we want to find the equation of the *tangent* to the *parabola* $y = f(x)$ at the point $(2, 4)$. (Note that $f(2) = 2^2 + 2 \cdot 2 - 4 = 4$.) Assume that it is given by the equation
$$
y = m(x-2) + 4, \tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $m$ is its *slope*.

Let's consider the intersection of the parabola with the tangent; this is given by the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
y &=& x^2 + 2x - 4,
\\ y &=& m(x-2)+4. 
\end{cases}
$$
In other words, to find the intersection, we should solve the *quadratic*  equation
$ x^2 + 2x - 4 = m(x-2)+4$, or
$$ 
x^2 + (2-m)x+(2m-8) = 0. \tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$
using the quadratic formula like so
$$
\frac{-(2-m)\pm\sqrt{(2-m)^2-4.1.(2m-8)}}{2.1}
$$
*Pictorially* it is clear that the tangent meets the parabola meets in exactly one point, so we want $(\ast \ast)$ to have a **unique solution**. This implies that the **discriminant of $(\ast \ast)$ vanishes**: 
$$
\begin{array}{crcl}
&(2-m)^2 - 4 \cdot (2m-8) &=& 0 
\\ \implies \qquad & m^2 - 12m + 36 &=& 0.
\end{array}
$$
Conveniently (although this is *not* a numerical coincidence), this equation has a unique solution $m=6$: this is the solution we are after. Plugging $m=6$ in $(\ast)$, we get the equation of the tangent at $(2, 4)$ to be $y = 6x-8$.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful

Comment: @Max If this answered your question, don't forget to check the green checkmark by the votes to mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 3):

Another method that can be used which is traditionally taught before derivatives is the limit (they're very similar but this is more intuitive):

Let $f(x) = x^2 + 2x - 4$ and $f'(x)$ be the tangent line at any point $a$ on the curve $f(x)$

Difference quotient:

$$f'(x) =\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}$$

What this essentially means is that we we take the slope between two points $a$ and $a+h$ as $h$ gets very small or as $h\rightarrow0$ the point $a+h$ gets closer to $a$ until there mathematically the slope is tangent to the point $a$.

$$f'(x) =\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{[(a+h)^2+ 2(a+h) - 4] - [(a)^2 - 2(a) - 4]}{h} $$
$$=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{[(h^2 + 2ah + a^2) + (2a + 2h) - 4] - [a^2 - 2a - 4]}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h^2 + 2ah + 2h}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} h + 2a + 2$$
$$= 2a + 2$$

There's your formula for the slope at any value $a$ along the curve $f(x)$

Sorry, I misread your post now I see that you want the equation!

We'll right the formula out in the form $y = mx + b$

Well we can begin with finding the slope of the line at $a = 2$

$$m = 2a + 2$$
$$= 2(2) + 2$$
$$= 6$$

The point at $x = 2$ is $(2,4)$ since if we plug $x = 2$ into $f(x)$ we end up with $y = 4$

So,

$$y = mx+b$$
$$4 = 6(2) + b$$
$$4 - 12 = b$$
$$-8 = b$$

Therefore your equation is:

$$y = 6x - 8$$

Answer (score 3):

## General formulas

$y=f(x)=x^2+2x-4$
$m=f'(x)=2x+2$  Slope equation

## Point-Slope equation of a line

$(y-y_0)=m_0\cdot(x-x_0)$

### Compute actual values

$x_0 = 2$
$y_0=f(x_0)=f(2)=(2)^2+2(2)-4=4+4-4=4$ 
$m_0=f'(x_0)=f'(2)=2(2)+2=4+2=6$

### Substitute values into the line equation

$y-4=6\cdot(x-2)$
$y=6\cdot(x-2)+4$
$y=6x-8$

### General Formula for a tangent line to a Parabola @ point $x_0$ on the Parabola

$y=f'(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the point $(x_1,y_1)=(x_1,f(x_1))$ for the general curve  $y=f(x)$ where tangent equation is desired.

Elementary differentiation familiarity is assumed. The tangent has general equation

$$ \dfrac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}= \dfrac {dy}{dx} \big{|}_{x=x_1.}  $$

For the particular parabola given, plug in coordinate values

$$ \dfrac{y-4}{x-2}= 6  $$

Or,

$$ y=6x-8. $$

Comment: This is amazingly elegant. $(+1)$

Answer (score 0):

An answer that assumes no knowledge of the tangent line equation.

We are looking for the tangent line to the graph of

$$f(x)= x²+2x - 4$$  $$at$$ $$x=2$$.

(1) The tangent line will " touch" the graph of function $f$ at point $( 2,f(2)) = (2,4)$. Let's call this point $P$.

(2) The equation of the tangent line will have form : $y= ax+b$. ( Any line that is neither horizontal nor vertical has an equation with such a form). ***So our problem is reduced to : what is number $a$? what is number $b$?***

(3) The slope of the tangent , namely, number " $a$, " will be , by definition, the number $f'(2)$. ( Explanation : the output of the derivative function $f'$ for an arbitrary input  $x = c$ is the instantaneous rate of change of function $f$ at $x=c$, and this instantaneous rate of change of $f$ is nothing else but the slope of the tangent line to the graph of function $f$ at point $( c, f(c) )$  ).

Since ( assuming  derivation formula : $[ax^n]'= a(n)x^{n-1}$ )

$$f'(x)=2x+2$$,

we consequently have $a = f'(X_P)=f'(2) = 2(2)+2 = 6$.

(4) Plugging $a=6$ in the equation of the tangent, we get :

$$y=6x+b$$.

(5) ***Any point of the tangent will verify the equation of this line, and, in particular, the point $P = (X_P, Y_P)=(2, 4)$***. ( Let's recall that, by definition,  point $P$ lies both on the graph of function $f$ and on the tangent line to this graph at $x=2$). Since, as we said, point P " obeys" the equation of the tangent, we have :

$$Y_P=6X_P+b$$

But we know that : $Y_P=4$ and $X_P=2$

Therefore ,

$4=6(2)+b$ , which implies $4 = 12 + b$ and $b=-8$.

(6) Having found both the slope ( number $a$ ) and number $b$, we can write that the equation of the tangent line we were looking for is :

$$y=6x + (-8)$$

or

$$y=6x-8$$.