# finding a tangent line to a parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I am practicing for a math contest and I encountered the following problem that I don't know how to solve:

For which value of $b$ is there only **one** intersection between the line $y = x + b$ and the parabola $y = x^2 + 5x + 3$?

How do I solve it?

Edit:
I made a mistake typing the problem. It should be $y = x^2 - 5x + 3$ instead of $y = x^2 + 5x + 3 $ the answer key says the answer is -6.

Comment: Do you know how to find a derivative?

Comment: Simply $x^2+5x+3=x+b$ must have only one solution, i.e. $x^2+4x+(3-b)=0$ should have zero discriminant.

Comment: A Parabola could have many tangent lines...However, it has only 1 min. value, may be this one is the one you are after. More here:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zz7e1nwgf9  and here:info:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92165/how-do-i-find-the-equation-of-a-tangent-line-to-a-curve

Comment: @NoChance Your observation would be relevant if the line’s equation were of the form $y=b$. The line in the problem is not horizontal, though.

Comment: @amd, thanks for your comment. I am not sure which tangent line one should pick then?

Comment: @NoChance If you’re going to to that route, then you want the one that has the same slope as the given line.

Comment: If this problem is for a math contest, I think it's more likely the problem was written with a non-calculus solution in mind. (Also, the question is tagged [tag:algebra-precalculus].)

Comment: @amd clear now thanks.

Comment: By raising/lowering the straight line by manipulating or changing of variable $b$ we can produce 1) two cuts  or 2) one coincident double point or 3) nothing at all.  Eliminate $y$ and set discriminant of quadratic to zero ..when tangent option can be realized... to evaluate $b$.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hint:
$$x^2+5x+3=x+b\iff x^2+4x+3-b=0,$$ this quadratic equation should have exactly one solution therefore the discriminant $\Delta=?$

Answer (score 3):

The tangent to parabola has slope $y' = 2x+5$ which should be slope of line =1 at the point of contact. So point of contact is at x=-2. Substituting in parabola,we get y=-3. Now this point lies on line as well.

Comment: Sorry to modify your $1000\sqrt{2}=1,414$ reputation :)

Comment: Let it go to infinity!

Answer (score 3):

Note that you like the line $y=x+b$ to be tangent to the parabola. The slope of this line is $ m=1.$ Thus the derivative of your parabola should be the same as the slope of the tangent line. Find the point of the tangency and find the $b$ value so that the line passes through that point.